# Unity - How to add score after destroying object in unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scoreloop

Before this, I have made a scoring section to my program that used Invoke repeating every 1s. Now, I have problem how to make my scoring counter add an additional score when I destroy some objects.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
{

  public Button[] buttons;
  public Button pauseButton;
  public Image[] images;
  public Text scoreText;
  public Text highScoreText;
  public Text yourScoreText;
  public Text text;
  bool gameOver;
  int score;
  levelscroller level;
  CoinMove cm;
  void Start()
  {
      gameOver = false;
      score = 0 + cm.plus;
      InvokeRepeating("scoreUpdate", 1.0f, 1.0f);
  }
  void Update()
  {
      storeHighScore(score);
      scoreText.text = "" + score;
      yourScoreText.text = "" + score;
      highScoreText.text = "" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore");
  }
  void scoreUpdate()
  {
      if (gameOver == false)
      {
          score += 1;
      }
  }
  void storeHighScore(int newHighscore)
  {
      int oldHighscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore", 0);
      if (newHighscore > oldHighscore)
      {
          PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore", newHighscore);
          oldHighscore = newHighscore;
          PlayerPrefs.Save();
      }
  }
```

Another class:

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 public class CoinMove : MonoBehaviour
 {
  public float Speed;
  public int plus = 0;
  UIManager ui;
  void Start()
  {

  }
  void Update()
  {
      transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, -1, 0) * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
      //if (Input.touchCount > 0 || Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
      //{
      //    Destroy(transform.gameObject);  
      //}
  }
  private void OnMouseDown()
  {
      Destroy(gameObject);
      plus += 10;
  }
}
```

It just make the counter of score totally 0 and not do the increment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get the logic behind you `int plus` value and reference to `CoinMove cm` and `UIManager ui`...

The easiest way to achieve what you are trying would be to simply reference your **UIManager** with `UIManager ui` in your **CoinMove** script, add a new method to **UIManager**:

```
public void AddScore(int scoreToAdd)
{
    score += scoreToAdd;
}
```

And then when you want to destroy your coin in your **CoinMove** script, call for this method **before** destroying your object:

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    ui.AddScore(plus);
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: It can't destroy the object. So, I move ui.AddScore(plus) under the Destroy method. It can destroy the object. But, it still increment by 1 score per second. When I pass value e.g 10 in AddScore's parameter, it didn't add 10 in my scoreboard

Comment: Did you make sure your `plus` value was set to 10 before calling `ui.AddScore(plus);` ? In my exemple, I didn't called `plus += 10;` as you did because I guess the value has to be set in the Inspector.

Comment: Also when you said _"It can't destroy the object."_, what do you mean exactly? Do you have an error in the console? (If so, make sure you have set the `ui` variable by drag-and-dropping your object containing the **UIManager** to the variable in the Inspector).

Comment: Yes, I've deleted 'plus += 1' . I just set 'ui.AddScore(10);'

Comment: It can destroy the object when I put    Destroy(gameObject);
above    ui.AddScore(plus);
My problem is the score.

Comment: I get it that the item is destroyed if `Destroy(gameObject);` is above. In this situation, the score isn't updated because you destroy your object: therefore you can't call `ui.AddScore(plus);` anymore. When `ui.AddScore(plus);` is called first, I think a problem may be occurring since you tell the the object isn't destroyed: it should. Have you check your console?

Comment: Yes. But, the gameObject isn't destroyed at all, and the score isn't updated

Comment: If the object isn't destroyed, it means the `Destroy(gameObject);` line wasn't reached. Have you tried using breakpoints to follow the script execution ? (You can do it with [MonoDevelop](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/monodevelops-debugger) or with [VisualStudio](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/debugging-unity-games-visual-studio))

Comment: Yes. From Visual Studio and it is reached

Comment: Well if `Destroy(gameObject);` is reached but object is not destroyed, it may come from something else in your project... Is it possible to you to compress it and send it?

Comment: have you made a reference to your Text Objects? did you dragged the GameObject to the inspector?

Comment: @Kardux sure, where I can send it?

Comment: You can upload it on a dropbox/wetransfer/... and either send the link here or to mail mail (which you can find on my [github](https://github.com/Kardux))

Answer (score 0):

First off:

- Don't use PlayerPrefs every frame, behind the scenes, unity is using IO for saving the file. you'd want to save the highscore when the game is over.
- in UIManager, you'd manage the score incrementing. Actually, it's best practice to handle Score incrementing in a controller (like a class called GameController) so the UI scripts only have mapping functions, (value to text fields for example). By splitting up controllers and UI, you can expand and change things more easily.

For the sake of simplicity let's ignore what I think is a cleaner version of programming.

Every object that holds a score value, can be added to the script (in your example, its CoinMove):

```
public int scoreValue;
```

This can be configured in the inspector to whatever value you want, or give it a standard value if you like.

CoinMove should have the following method:

```
public void AddScore(int amount) {
    score += amount;
}
```

Because you have a reference to UIManager in CoinMove, in coinMove we can do:

```
private void OnMouseDown()
  {
      Destroy(gameObject);
      ui.AddScore(scoreValue);
  }
```

Comment: I've tried this method before. But, it still increment by 1 score per second. When I pass value e.g 10 in AddScore's parameter, it didn't add 10 in my scoreboard